# Disabling WooCommerce add to cart button after first click prevents submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to disable the WooCommerce *Add to cart* button when the user clicks it for two reasons..

- To prevent multiple clicks on it
- To show the user their click did something

I used this code:

```
if ($('body').filter('.single-product')) {

    var add_cart_button = $('.single_add_to_cart_button');

    /* Disable button on add to bag click if button is active */

    add_cart_button.on('click', function(e) {

        if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true); // Prevent multi adds
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }

    });

}
```

Whilst this works, it also seems to disable the button even working, the adding of the product doesn't work as the form submit seems to not fire at all.

Why is this happening and what do I need to change here?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by doing it with the submit event instead...

Since the `form` doesn't have a `name` attribute I had to target it another way:

```
if ($('body').filter('.single-product')) {

    var add_cart_button = $('.single_add_to_cart_button');

    add_cart_button.closest('form').on('submit', function(e) {

        var cur_atc_button = $(this).find('.single_add_to_cart_button');

        if (!cur_atc_button.hasClass('disabled')) {
            cur_atc_button.addClass('disabled');
        }

    });

}
```

**Edit:** I removed the below disabling of the button (using `addClass` instead) as it seems for some item types it failed to add the item to the cart if you did this:

```
cur_atc_button.prop('disabled', true); // Prevent multi adds
```

If anyone knows why, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Brett's solution was not enough, so I found another way:

```
var atc_button = $("button.single_add_to_cart_button");

//prevent multiple clicks on add-to-cart
$("form.cart").submit(function() {
    //disable subsequent submits
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    //show button as disabled
    if (!atc_button.hasClass('disabled')) {
        atc_button.addClass('disabled');
    }
    return true;
});
```